# Prevent false date to string conversion

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, type-conversion

I'm new to AppScripts (JavaScript).

I want to automate an accounting sheet. I have a lot of account numbers and headings in column A. To only keep the account numbers I only want to keep the values where the first character is numeric.
Therefore I use this code:

```
[...]
for (var k = 0; k < values.length; k++) {
      var accountNumber= values[k][0].toString();
      
      if (!isNaN(parseInt(accountNumber[0], 10))) {
    
        var alreadyExists = allAccounts.some(function(existingValue) {
          return existingValue[0] === accountNumber;
        });

        if (!alreadyExists) {
          allAccounts.push([accountNumber, values[k][1]]);
        }
      }
    }
[...]
```

My problem ist that there is a account number "1217 10", which GoogleSheets detects as a date. If I convert this row to a string it's converted to this "Sun Sep 24 00:44:07 GMT+00:53 1217". Which is obviously not my intention.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of this code you can modify your code to set the format of the entire column to plain text:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

var range = sheet.getRange("A:A");
range.setNumberFormat('@'); 

for (var k = 0; k < values.length; k++) {
  var accountNumber = values[k][0].toString();

  if (!isNaN(parseInt(accountNumber[0], 10))) {

    var alreadyExists = allAccounts.some(function(existingValue) {
      return existingValue[0] === accountNumber;
    });

    if (!alreadyExists) {
      allAccounts.push([accountNumber, values[k][1]]);
    }
  }
}

range.setNumberFormat('General');
```